# Why doesn't wget url/mediafile.ext > medafile2.ext work?

Tags: command-line, zsh, io-redirection, wget

I tried the following :

```
[$] wget http://cdn.edgecast.steamstatic.com/steam/apps/256679148/movie480.webm > Conan1.webm 
                                                    [1:21:05]
--2017-02-23 01:51:50--  http://cdn.edgecast.steamstatic.com/steam/apps/256679148/movie480.webm
Resolving cdn.edgecast.steamstatic.com (cdn.edgecast.steamstatic.com)... 117.18.232.131
Connecting to cdn.edgecast.steamstatic.com (cdn.edgecast.steamstatic.com)|117.18.232.131|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 11255413 (11M) [video/webm]
Saving to: ‘movie480.webm’

movie480.webm                       100%[===================================================================>]  10.73M  33.7KB/s    in 6m 25s  

2017-02-23 01:58:16 (28.6 KB/s) - ‘movie480.webm’ saved [11255413/11255413]
```

As can be seen the first part of the command worked, wget downloaded the file but the second part of the command that renaming the file, in this case a very generic movie480.webm was downloaded. Why wasn't conan1.webm , the name I had suggested it took.

I do know that if I had done -

```
$ mv  movie480.webm conan1.webm
```

then it would work, but this means an additional command. Why that failed ? Could there have been another way to do the same thing in a single command though similar to shown above?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You didn't "suggest it took" the name `Conan1.webm`, you redirected its standard output stream to file called `Conan1.webm`. Since `wget` doesn't write to standard output by default, that has no effect on where the content is saved.

See `man wget` - in particular the `-O` option:

```
-O file
--output-document=file
    The documents will not be written to the appropriate files, but all
    will be concatenated together and written to file.  If - is used as
    file, documents will be printed to standard output, disabling link
    conversion.  (Use ./- to print to a file literally named -.)
```

So you could have used

```
wget -O Conan1.webm http://cdn.edgecast.steamstatic.com/steam/apps/256679148/movie480.webm
```

or

```
wget -O- http://cdn.edgecast.steamstatic.com/steam/apps/256679148/movie480.webm > Conan1.webm
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the `>` symbol to `-O`. `>` is used to redirect the text that the command normally prints to the screen (only its stdout, to be more accurate) to a file. A file created with `>` contains the text normally printed to the screen.

Comment: It's *kind* of the shell output; it's really wget's stdout output, which would follow the shell's stdout.